# Performance cache vs DB vs network traffic

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-2008, caching, traffic

My colleague and I, are in a middle of a project running out of time. We found an existing code where we were discussing about the performance about cache, db and network traffic.

This is not a question exclusively to load from cache vs db, because the answer is obvious that cache is the sole answer.

I am talking about a table-valued function in Sql Server 2008 that returns the 3000 rows and 12 non-indexed columns from 2 tables in total.

One of these 2 tables is already in cache. We need to go through database anyway to retrieve the data from table that is not cached.

Is it better to iterate with all the data exclusively returned from DB and map our objects (in that case we won't need to load the cached data because everything was returned from DB) or it should be better to return just the ID from DB for the cached object (to reduce network traffic) and load the info from cache during the 3000 iterations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, are you asking if you should load the data for table 2 on the fly as you iterate through the records (while loading or otherwise)?  If that's what you're asking I think the answer is very likely that it will be significantly slower just in terms of network latency.  Each call to your database incurs a significant cost just in round trip time to the DB server.  A lot depends on what that latency is...

Answer (score 0):

Decide and stick with one decision or benchmark both solutions.